# How to use MethodInfo.Invoke to set property value?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class with a property Value like this:

```
public class MyClass {
   public property var Value { get; set; }
   ....
}
```

I want to use MethodInfo.Invoke() to set property value. Here are some codes:

```
object o;
// use CodeDom to get instance of a dynamically built MyClass to o, codes omitted
Type type = o.GetType();
MethodInfo mi = type.GetProperty("Value");
mi.Invoke(o, new object[] {23}); // Set Value to 23?
```

I cannot access to my work VS right now. My question is how to set Value with a integer value such as 23?

Comment: Use PropertyInfo.SetValue, as mentioned below.  If you ever find that you are constrained to using a MethodInfo object, obtain the "get" method of the property (PropertyInfo.GetGetMethod()), and invoke it as above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [PropertyInfo.SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1.aspx) method.

```
object o;
//...
Type type = o.GetType();
PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty("Value");
pi.SetValue(o, 23, null);
```

Comment: actually it should be: pi.SetValue(o, 23, null); ? not 0

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **.NET Framework 4.6 and 4.5**, you can also use [PropertyInfo.SetMethod Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setmethod(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
object o;
//...
Type type = o.GetType();
PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty("Value");
pi.SetMethod.Invoke(o, new object[] {23});
```